# Долго выполняется скалярная функция

Tags: sql, sql-server

Написал не очень сложную скалярную функцию, которая сравнивает наименования в двух таблицах и, при совпадении, добавляет код(или несколько кодов) к наименованию.

```
declare
    @PostCode varchar(8000) = '',
    @PostName varchar(300)

SELECT @PostName = pb.[FullName]
FROM [spr].[PostsBaseV] pb
WHERE IdPostBase = @IdPostBase
SELECT  @PostCode = @PostCode + [PostCode] + ', '
FROM [DESR].[spr].[PostsCodeV]
where name = @PostName 
IF len(@PostCode) > 1
SELECT @PostCode = LEFT(@PostCode, NULLIF(LEN(@PostCode)-1,-1))
  RETURN(@PostCode) 
END
```

В сравниваемой таблице 7000 строк. Выполнение запроса занимает более минуты, что неприемлемо. Посему вопрос - как можно оптимизировать запрос? Есть ли альтернатива скалярной функции. Я понимаю, что загруженность вызвана большим кол-ом строк в таблице, но как решить вопрос пока не знаю.

Comment: для начала надо посмотреть план выполнения каждого отдельного sql запроса и понять почему он может долго выполняться и не нужен ли ему для работы какой нибудь индекс

Comment: Я смотрел план, если использовать прямой запрос через селект, то 99% используется на просмотр кластер.индекса. А если использовать в процедуре(как я и делаю), то 97% используется на сортировку, если ее убрать, то 55 на индекс и 40% на все остальное

Comment: может ему top 1 дать в запросах, что бы он знал что будет только одна строка